# Don't receive emails after restoring mails on postfix (ubuntu-server)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, backup, restore

I recently swichted my virtual server and for that reason I had to move the whole postfix from the old to the new server.

I created an archive (.tar.gz) for each domain in `/var/qmail/mailnames/`

For example: There is an email address `help@me.net`. So I've created a `me.net.tar.gz` archive from `/var/qmail/mailnames/me.net`.

**Old** server: Ubuntu 12.04, Plesk 10 or 11

**New** server: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Plesk 12.5

The first step was creating a plesk user for the `me.net` domain, added via that user the `help@me.net` email address and tested it: worked.
The next step was uploading the previously created `me.net.tar.gz` to the new server and extracting it in `/var/qmail/mailnames/me`
The last step was rebooting postfix.

The result: Everything looks fine: I have all my old mails in all my old IMAP folders.

**But:** **I do not receive emails anymore.** I can compose and send new mails, they are listed in the sent folder and they appear in the receiver mailbox. If I write an email to this address (like before extracting the archive with the old files), nothing happens. I don't get any error messages (e.g. mail address not reachable or does not exist etc.). I can send mails and read old mails via different devices and email clients, but I can't receive anymore...

Does anyone know this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You say that you are using postfix, but your mail is in /var/qmail? Please confirm...

Comment: That's right. In my opinion it's weird, yes, but the mails are definitely in /var/qmail (not in /etc/postfix as expected).

Answer (score 0):

So, you got e-mail on the new server (your test e-mail). Then you untarred all your old e-mail, and now you do not receive e-mail any more?

Check the owner and permissions of your files. My crystal ball thinks that postfix cannot write to the directories that you have untarred.

If you don't see the problem, please provide a snippet of /var/log/maillog that shows the delivery attempt.